# MySQL Error: #1142 - SELECT command denied to user

Tags: mysql, select, command

I'm having troubles with a certain query on one of my servers. On all other places I've tested it it works completely fine but on the server i want to use it it isn't working.

It's about the following SQL:

```
SELECT facturen.id            AS fid, 
       projecten.id           AS pid, 
       titel, 
       facturen.totaal_bedrag AS totaal, 
       betaald, 
       datum 
FROM   facturen, 
       projecten 
WHERE  facturen.project_id = projecten.id 
       AND projecten.eigenaar = '1' 
ORDER  BY datum DESC
```

This is the error code I get from it:

`SELECT command denied to user 'marco'@'localhost' for table 'projecten'`

The tables:
facturen:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facturen` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lever_datum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaal_bedrag` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `btw` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `bedrijf` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `contactpersoon` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `adres` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `plaats` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `betaald` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=201200006 ;
```

projecten:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projecten` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `titel` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `eigenaar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creatie_datum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eind_datum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaal_bedrag` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `btw` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=201200004 ;
```

The strange part is that every other query on both the 'projecten' table and the 'facturen' table works completely fine, also this query works fine on two other servers of mine.

Comment: what is bt2 in bt2.projecten ?

Comment: A typo of mine from mine since I copied it to here from my old database. It wasn't there on the main database so the problem isn't solved through. Also it's not a privilege problem since I got full access.

Comment: Can you print out the results of your privileges table?

Comment: @matthewdavidson, granted and all privileges ;)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but have you tried using qualified names for the fields that don't have a name conflict? So `projecten.titel`, and the like?

Comment: another reason might be your account don't have the permission.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I faced the same situation but it's funny that the reason for the error was due to the use of incorrect database or schema name.

It's true that multiple issues can lead to the error you have mentioned.

Comment: +1 Yes, its possible.  I hit this too.. In my case my new table name had a '.' accidentally. I wanted the table name to be MAP.DATE where DATE is timestamp. Its made it think like a schema. I replace . with _ eventually and it worked

Comment: bit more funny in my case.
i just logged out and logged in.

`it worked for me :)`

Comment: Yes, thats true. In my case the schema name was wrong. After changing to correct schema name, query worked

Comment: yes, it is highly possible. I already grant all permission for user but still get `denied` error.

Comment: Yes correct.I am also faced the same issue.

Answer (score 19):

You need to grant SELECT permissions to the MySQL user who is connecting to MySQL

same question as here [Error: select command denied to user '<userid>'@'<ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)

see answers of the link ;)

Comment: Already tried that and it still isn't working, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same issue now. User has privileges, but can't select from this one table.

Comment: It can be wrong SELECT expression, this occurs in 5.7 (seems more strict)

Comment: In my case, I used a user that was created only for the task, and this user did not have access to the `temp` database which my normal user can access. I did not understand this. Therefore, I created a new connection to the host in my rdms editor and visually checked whether the connection worked at all, created the connection, and then I saw the missing database.

Answer (score 10):

**This error also arises for a syntax error occurred due to tablename aliasing.**

For instance, when executing below query,

> select * from a.table1, b.table2 where a.table1= b.table2

below error occurs:

> MySQL Error: #1142. Response form the database. SELECT command denied to user "username@ip" for table "table1"

**Solution** : Syntax to alias tablename should be used properly, syntax solution for above instance:

> select * from table1 a,  table2 b where a.table1= b.table2

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too and for me, the problem was that I moved to a new server and the database I was trying to connect to with my PHP code changed from "my_Database" to "my_database".

Answer (score 4):

This is th privileges issue in your database users. first check and grant permission to user
'marco' in localhost

Answer (score 2):

I just emptied my session data then it worked again. Here is where you find the button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this error, because I copied stored procedure from localhost and there the db name was different then on the server I wanted to use it. It took me a couple of hours to figure out, why I don't have permissions to execute the procedure... Check you db names pls :D Hope someone finds this useful...

Answer (score 1):

So the issue I ran into was this...   the application I used to grant the permissions converted the Schema.TableName into a single DB statement in the wrong table, so the grant was indeed wrong, but looked correct when we did a SHOW GRANTS FOR UserName if you weren't paying very close attention to GRANT SELECT vs GRANT TABLE SELECT.  Manually correcting the Grant Select on Table w/ proper escaping of `Schema`.`Table` solved my issue.

May be unrelated, but I can imagine if one client does this wrong, another might too.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem as well, the case with me was incorrect naming . I was migrating from local server to online server.
my SQL command had "**database.tablename.column**" structure. the name of database in online server was different. for example my code was "**pet.item.name**"  while it needed to be "**pet_app.item.name**"
changing database name solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but posting here for newbies.
So in my case, I'm using Laravel 9 with 2 Databases (MySQL)
and In my localhost, it works perfectly but on live hosting, I am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied
```

so after surfing around I found that I am using the wrong database name which causes the error. So be double sure to check both databases' names as per PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened on my server when I imported a view with an invalid definer.

Removing the faulty view fixed the error.

The error message didn't say anything about the view in question, but was "complaining" about one of the tables, that was used in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give privileges to the particular user by giving the command mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES *.* To 'username'@'localhost'; and then give FLUSH PRIVILEGES; command.
Then it won't give this error.., hope it helps thank you..!

Comment: Please add this type of answer in the comment.

Comment: @PratikBhajankar with reputation < 50, you cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you using/connect more then one databases then you should use same DB_USERNAME for all databases

I had the same issue solved by using same DB_USERNAME for all databases ,
because i was use/connect multiple databases in same project and every database DB_USERNAME was different so when i run the query select,update, delete etc from multiple database then was get this error.

because if you use more then one table in query and the database DB_USERNAME is different you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to issue `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_METRICS;` on a so-called "budget host."  I got 1142 because reading that particular system table requires the `PROCESS` privilege and the user didn't have it. I had to fool around to figure out it was `PROCESS` and not some other privilege that was missing.

(No, the "budget host" won't grant that priv to the user. They probably don't want their customers to see how ridiculously overloaded their servers are. Because MySQL licenses are expens .... wait, no they're free.)

Answer (score -3):

In MySQL query browser go to Tools tab>MySQL Administrator  > User Administration and then give the privileges to user.

Comment: the question wasn't about some unspecified browser, just pure MySQL