# MySQL error 1142 DROP command denied

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedures

I can't drop a table from a procedure.
This is the procedure in which it gives me the error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procDropAllTables`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE end_of_tables INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT t.table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables t 
        WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_of_tables = 1;

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    OPEN cur;

    tables_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO table_name;

        IF end_of_tables = 2 THEN
            LEAVE tables_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' , table_name);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
END
```

I can drop drop tables if I do it manualy, so it isnt a user privileges problem

Comment: Sure it's not a privileges issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user

Comment: Yes I'm sure it isn't a privileges issue.