# cant access some tables from database when published online

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

so i already created a user on web hosting and gave it all privileges, all tables from database are working normally except my table reservation, the error says

[here is where i gave all privilages on the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTdNR.png)

> "Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user
>   'tamayode_user'@'localhost' for table 'reservations''"

what would be its cause, im using pdo and php
its different from some answers here saying i should allow all privillages because i already done that and it fully works locally but i need it to work online. i already granted or allow all privileges from the user to the database

Comment: Despite what you claim, it sounds like you haven't granted all privileges on the `reservations` table. Please show the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR tamayode_user@localhost;`

Comment: It's already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user

Comment: @Tegr4 i granted all privilages on the database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just changed the port for the localhost. Try it.

Comment: no post number for localhost

Comment: port number... @Hepthistus

Comment: yes no port number just localhost

Comment: im running it in webhosting its completely fine locally but when i published it all moduleregarding reservation wont work