# Download MySQL database from ISP server to localhost

Tags: mysql

Non-coder here, please advise as newbie. I have a MySQL DB on my ISP's server that provides data for a web site. I want to set up a db on my localhost that I can use for local development. The DBs don't need to be linked, nor do they need to remain synchronized. I just need to start with a current copy of the ISP version.

I have used PHPMyAdmin on ISP to download what I think is a dump file. the file, [mydbname].sql shows the schema and all the data. I just can't figure out how to import it in MySQL Workbench on my local PC.

Using the MySQL Workbench Data Import tab, if I execute "Import from Dump Project Folder" where the .sql file is located, I get "There were no dump files in the selected folder."

If I select "Import from Self-Contained File" and select my ***.sql file, I get "ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 31: CREATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'account' Operation failed with exitcode 1"

I've attempted to give 'root'@'localhost' all privileges.

I'm guessing there's an issue with privileges. If there's another way to do this, I'd be thrilled to know it. Many thanks!

Comment: Look that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a sql dump file then try this on the CLI:

```
mysql -h hostname -u user --password=password databasename < filename
```

Assuming of course that  has the right privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
Non-coder here, please advise as newbie.
```

In that case, download heidisql : https://www.heidisql.com/
It also makes copying tables and database from server to server very easy.

Apart from that: there is most likely something wrong with your privileges. But you might have made that worse by trying to give privileges to root. The root user can already do everything. So maybe also have a look at this post : [How can I restore the MySQL root user’s full privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges)