# SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'table'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have deployed my database on MySQL Database server. I have a user 'bedgeaj_root@localhost' and it has all the permissions. But it still giving me the error :

> SELECT command denied to user 'bedgeaj_root'@'localhost' for table 'transactions'

While searching on the net, I studied that it is some user permission issue. But I don't understand that why it is giving this error as I have given all the permission to this user.

Here is the screen shot of my cPanel user permissions screen:

[image: bedgeaj_root@localhost permissions screen]

Here goes my stack trace:

```
   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : itemizedStatementReport_patientBalance
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:246)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1073)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1235)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:859)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:804)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:652)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
... 1 more


   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'bedgeaj_root'@'localhost' for table 'transactions'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:239)
... 9 more
```

I am using this query:

```
    SELECT alias.patient_id , SUM(alias.balance) AS balance
    from (
    SELECT v.patient_id,trx.trx_id,trx.trx_status,trx.trx_seq,pb.billing_id,v.visit_id,v.visit_dt,forma t(SUM(tl.net_amount) - ifnull((SELECT SUM(pl.applied_amount+pl.discount_amount) FROM payment_lines pl where pl.trx_line_id = tl.trx_line_id),0.0),2)AS balance
    FROM ((transactions trx JOIN trx_lines tl ON (trx.trx_id = tl.trx_id))JOIN patient_billing pb ON(pb.billing_id = trx.billing_id))JOIN visits v ON (pb.visit_id = v.visit_id)
    where trx.trx_seq='4' AND trx.trx_status='PENDING' AND (date_format(v.visit_dt,'%Y/%m/%d')<date_format(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day),'%Y/%m/%d'))
    group by tl.trx_id) alias
    where alias.patient_id = $P{patient_id}
```

group by alias.patient_id]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "as I have given all the permission to this user." - doesn't appear that way.

Comment: I have assigned the user bedgea_root@localhost all the permissions including SELECT permission. All other queries run fine except one specific query.

Comment: SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER; What do you get?

Comment: It gives me following results :
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'bedgeaj_root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*423473EB2836A
93BE438D8C5185F0CA50D47F1B0' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bedgeaj\_medmax`.* TO 'bedgeaj_root'@'localhost'

Comment: Are you sure transactions table is in the DB?

Comment: I have now provided the stack trace also.

Comment: Show us your query,sometimes a query error might be mistaken as a permission issue.

Comment: Ofcorse the transaction table is in the DB. My application uses the same table on for other different modules, and it runs fine there. But here, i am using that table in a report with some joins to other tables.

Comment: I now double checked the tables that I am using in the query that whether they exists in DB or not. They do exist in the Database.

Comment: If its just this query its clear that the query has a mistake in it,I think.

Comment: But if I run the same query through mysql workbench , it runs fine. Also it runs fine on my local system, but it is giving this error on the Database server of our production server(A linux based server).

Answer (score 5):

```
grant all privileges on bedgeaj_medmax.transactions to 'bedgeaj_root'@'%'  identified by 'password';
```

Try this one.

EDIT

[Error: select command denied to user '<userid>'@'<ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)

See comment by pisces in the above link.

Comment: I have now provided the stack trace also.

Comment: I now double checked the tables that I am using in the query that whether they exists in DB or not. They do exist in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My local database was created from a dump from another server and the local server didn't have all the right permissions for a user that was on the dev server. I got this error trying to backup my local database using sequel pro. Then I tried mysqldump and got a different error: Got error: 1449: The user specified as a definer ('joey'@'127.0.0.1') does not exist when using LOCK TABLES . So I granted all on . to joey@127.0.0.1 and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
In my situation, the error appeared because **MySQL** is **case sensitive** in **Linux**!

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently, the **case sensitivity** of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are **not case sensitive in Windows**, but are **case sensitive** in most varieties of **Unix**.

If `GRANT` command was run before, changing `tablename` to `TABLENAME`/`Tablename` can solve the problem.