# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005', problems trying to access on the DB, why?

Tags: mysql, database, asp-classic, odbc, rdbms

I have to work of a client website made in ASP and that use MySql as DB.

The problem is that when I try to open the website I obtain the following MySql error message:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.92-enterprise-gpl-log]SELECT command denied to user 'Sql_myDBname'@'ip of the DB' for table 'normative'

/home.asp, line 14
```

I entered in the DB (from the administration pannel of the hosting) and trying to open any tables I always obtain the previous error message.

Why? What it means? Why the user can't access to tables? Could be a problem of my hosting provider?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I hope user Sql_myDBname do not have access to normative table.

Comment: what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Could you post your connection string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: select command denied to user '<userid>'@'<ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)