# web application can't query from MySQL on server

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I have a web application (jsf+hibernate) deployed on a tomcat server that tries to connect to MySQL database on another server, I have added the web app server ip to be allowed when connecting to the MySQL server, when I start the app I get

```
23:55:50,077  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1142, SQLState: 42000
23:55:50,077 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - SELECT command denied to user 'xxx'@'yyyy' for table 'zzz'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract 

ResultSet
...
```

please note that, I have given the user all the privileges, also I can connect to the database from net beans and query normally.
also running the web application and the mysql on local host, working fine.

Comment: Have you read through the answers to similar questions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table

Comment: I had checked all those, except for ... the  table names, that is  schema_table  vs  schema.table

Comment: Did that resolve the issue?  If not, do you know what SELECT statement is being run?

Comment: the query is generated by hibernate, I can't change that. and yes the query is select this_.id as id1_5_0_, this_.owner_type as owner_ty2_5_0_ from schema.newgar_ownership this_

Comment: Is "schema" your database name locally and on the remote server?

Comment: you'r right, it was the database host, they add a suffix prior to the schema name, which was conflicting in hibernate catalog, please change it to answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the same database name locally and on the remote server.  Often database hosts add a prefix or suffix to the database name that is in conflict with what you have in hibernate.