# ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

Tags: mysql

I am getting mysql 1142 error on the following query

```
mysql> SELECT host, user ,password, Grant_priv, Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

Can someone help me with the ERROR 1142 (42000)?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9RgF.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: select command denied to user '<userid>'@'<ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work